# How to render a control to an image?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, bitmapimage, windows-store-apps

I want to render a grid as an image to use on a live tile in my Windows 8 Metro Style App.

Comment: There is no visual brush in WinRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WriteableBitmap.Render() is missing in WinRT your options are WriteableBitmapEx (CodePlex) or if you need fonts - Direct2D (you can use it from C# thanks to SharpDX).

Comment: How would you use WriteableBitmapEx for this? I've played around with it but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You don't get a Render method to render a grid, but you can [Blit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) bitmaps onto a bitmap to compose a combined picture to use in a tile. As I said though - it only supports bitmap operations and some simple shapes. For using fonts or anything fancier you would either need to use DirectX or dig into some serious image processing algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no way to render image from control.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/752372e6-7208-4d92-924c-97177182a69f

Thanks.

Comment: Too bad there is simple way to do this.